# excluding root/base directory from an array using File::Find::Rule

Tags: perl, file-handling

I am trying to read in the subdirectories using File::Find::Rule, but my code is also printing/reading the base dir too along with the subdirectories. how can I correct the use of cvs example (http://search.cpan.org/~rclamp/File-Find-Rule-0.34/lib/File/Find/Rule.pm) method which has been explained in some of the similar posts. My code looks like -

```
 use File::Find::Rule;
my $directory = './test_dir/';
my $rule = File::Find::Rule->new; $rule -> or($rule ->new
        -> directory
        ->name('test_dir')
        ->prune
        ->discard,
          $rule->new);
my @subdirs = $rule->in($directory);
```

which still lists ./test_dir as well in the @subdir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) to exclude the search directory.

```
my @subdirs = grep { $_ ne $directory } $rule->in($directory);
```

In that case you would have to change the content of `$directory` to match the way File::Find outputs it, though. There is no trailing slash, and no leading `./`. Just use the name, or a direct relative path.

```
my $directory = 'test_dir';   
my $other_dir = 'foo/bar/baz'; # multi-level depths would look like this
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @simbabque, just one question - why is there  a new variable $other_dir?

Comment: @B_perl that was just my example for what it looks like if you have a path that is multiple directories deep. You don't need that variable. But if I put both examples in one code block in my answer, I want it to be _syntactically correct_ Perl.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thanks @simbabque..sorry I was just double checking incase I missed something.

Comment: No problem. It's always better to check. :)

Comment: @B I just realized you probably copied that code from an answer I wrote two years ago and which I do not remember. Small world. :)

Comment: Yes! I saw your username too in that post later, so I had mark it as useful! How knowledge transfers  :) Thanks!

Comment: @B the fun think is, I have never used this module. I am just good at reading documentation. That's a skill you need to learn too. ;-)